# python check for update script

Tags: python

As the title said, I would like that some of my python scripts have "check for update". I was reading and there a way creating a .txt file with the program version, but I would not like create a .txt file, I think that there another way for do that. I was thinking in read the content with the python file from de server and compare with the actual content, but At the same time I think that is a bad idea.

I thought in create a property "self.version = 1.0" but there a way that I can read the property of the python file from the server?? In this way is more easy comparing both.

Because the problem of creating a text file is that if I send the .py to a friend I have to send the txt file too, and what if I have 10 .py with 10 txtFiles, and if I update the version in the .py I have to do in the txt file and I think that is not very intuitive.

What you all recommend me?

Thanks!

Comment: One option is to use a property, like you mentioned. To compare the local version to the server version, you could download the file from the server and check the version in there. Or you could make an API endpoint in your server where you can check what the newest version is.

Comment: How I do that?? if I download the file to the temp for example, how I compare the version storage in the property?? and/or how can I do this API EndPoint?

Comment: One naive way for comparison would be to have the version as a module property (a top level variable, usually all uppercase) at the top of the file; you donwload the new version from the server, use `open()` to read the new python file as text and find the line that contains the version property and compare that to the current version of the script.

Comment: Okay I see... I did a Split("\n") and select the index 0 where is the version and check it. That's cool, thanks so much. Put the answer like answer for close it with the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for version check between scripts could be this:

Put a module variable at the top of the script, like this for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__VERSION__ = '1.5'

# here goes the rest of the script
```

Then, to check for updates (this could go somewhere at the start of your script):

1. download the newest version of the script from the server (maybe use the `requests` library and save to somewhere on disk or in a temp file).
2. read the script as a text file to get its version

   ```
   new_version = ''
   with open('new_script.py') as f:
       for line in f:
           line = line.strip()
           if '__VERSION__' in line:
               _, new_version = line.split('=', maxsplit=1)
               new_version = new_version.strip()
               break

   print('Version of the new script is:', new_version)
   print('Current version is:', __VERSION__)
   ```